# Regex returns inter-phrase words as another quoted phrase

Tags: regex

Here's my regex expression...

```
(?<=")[^"]+(?=")|[-+@]?([\w]+(-*\w*)*)
```

And here's my test code...

```
"@One one" @two three four "fi-ve five" six se-ven "e-ight" "nine n-ine nine"
```

I don't want the double-quotes to be returned in the results, but that seems to make it return the parts that are between the other quoted phrases as a quoted phrase in itself. Here are the current results (excluding the single quotes)...

```
'@One one'
' @two three four '
'fi-ve five'
' six se-ven '
'e-ight'
' '
'nine n-ine nine'
```

whereas I really want it to return those as individual results (excluding the single quotes)...

```
'@One one'
'@two'
'three'
'four'
'fi-ve five'
'six'
'se-ven'
'e-ight'
'nine n-ine nine'
```

Any ideas what change would make the double-quotes only apply to the phrase itself, not the inter-quote words? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you've come across is that regexes don't have "memory" — that is, they can't remember whether last quotes were opening or closing (the same reason why regex is not good for parsing HTML/XML). However, if you can assume that the quoting follows the standard rules that there is no space between the quotation marks and the text being quoted (whereas, if there is a space between a quotation mark and the adjacent word, that word is not part of the quote), then you can use negative look-arounds `(?!\s)` and `(?<!\s)` to make sure there's no space in those places:

```
(?<=")(?!\s)[^"]+(?<!\s)(?=")|[-+@]?([\w]+(-*\w*)*)
```

To clarify what the assumptions are (using underscores to mark spaces in question):

```
"This is a quote"_this text is not a quote_"another quote"
^               ^ ^                      ^ ^             ^
  no space here   |                      |    none here
  between word    ⌞  but there is here   ⌟
  and mark
```

Edit: Also, you can simplify the regex a bit by removing the groups and using character classes:

```
(?<=")(?!\s)[^"]+(?!\s)(?=")|[-+@]?[\w]+[-\w]*
```

This makes it easier (for me anyway) to get the results:

```
>> str = "\"@One one\" @two three four \"fi-ve five\" six se-ven \"e-ight\" \"nine n-ine nine\""
=> "\"@One one\" @two three four \"fi-ve five\" six se-ven \"e-ight\" \"nine n-ine nine\""
>> rex = /(?<=")(?!\s)[^"]+(?!\s)(?=")|[-+@]?[\w]+[-\w]*/
=> /(?<=")(?!\s)[^"]+(?!\s)(?=")|[-+@]?[\w]+[-\w]*/
>> str.scan rex
=> ["@One one", "@two", "three", "four", "fi-ve five", 
    "six", "se-ven", "e-ight", "nine n-ine nine"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works when you search things one at a time.  I'm not sure in what context this is being used, but you could turn off any global flag and it would only match the first occurrence.  Then just trim that string off the front and run again, and so on.

EDIT: Does it matter what order you get them in?
How about two separate regexes?

First one: `"([^"]*)"`

This will match all quoted strings that you want to keep, do a regex replace with capture, you can capture all of them and replace them with empty strings.

Second:  Just match every word left after that.

Comment: I see what you mean, and I might keep that in my back pocket, but I would really like to get all the terms via the regex and not have to trim the string and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

## Description

This isn't perfect in that capture group 0 does contain the match including the leading / trailing spaces and quotes, but capture group 1 will get the text inside the quotes, and group 2 gets the individual words. This will work regardless of white space around individual quotes.

`(?!\Z)(?:\s*"([^"]*)"|\s*(\S*))`

[image]

## Example

Live Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/HrHJIlMieb

**Sample text**

Note the potentially difficult edge case between 5 and 6

```
"@One one" @two three four "fi-ve five"six se-ven "e-ight" "nine n-ine nine"
```

**Capture Groups**

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => "@One one"
        [1] =>  @two
        [2] =>  three
        [3] =>  four
        [4] =>  "fi-ve five"
        [5] =>  six
        [6] =>  se-ven
        [7] =>  "e-ight"
        [8] =>  "nine n-ine nine"
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => @One one
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => fi-ve five
        [5] => 
        [6] => 
        [7] => e-ight
        [8] => nine n-ine nine
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => @two
        [2] => three
        [3] => four
        [4] => 
        [5] => six
        [6] => se-ven
        [7] => 
        [8] => 
    )
```